# How to generate thumbnail images from a PDF file with JQuery / ASP.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax

I am working on project that allows the user to upload pdf files , store them in SQL Database , manipulate them (Comment, Highlight, Bookmark, Draw, Copy Text/Table/Image)and generate the files from HTML Pages .
To do the work , I chose to work using iTextSharp, it makes the work easier.
Back to the file uploaded ,I worked on the file uploading part , I have developed the work using ASP.Net MVC, and It works very well, but I want to add some features buy making the files uploaded appear like docs on the page using thumbnails of every doc. 
I wonder to know How can I generate thumbnails for pdf and add them to ASP.Net MVC .

I tried out this API , but it's not work very well with ASP.Net MVC
http://www.tallcomponents.com/pdfthumbnail-overview.aspx

I find this code using JQuery that generate thumbnails from images that are already uploaded , this code is part of long code .
I thought about using this script by adding another function that generates Images from PDF files , then using this code to making Popup thumbnails from the last image .

```
        $(".ImagePopLink").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $ID = $(this).html();
            var $imagebase = $("#hidImageBase").val();
            var $imagesource = $imagebase + "?ID=" + $ID;
            var $imagelink = "<img style=\"width: 400px\" src=\"" + $imagesource + "\" />";
            $("#divImg").html($imagelink);
            $("#divImg").load();
            $("#PopWindow").css({ "left": $.mouseX(e), "top": $.mouseY(e) + 5 });
            $("#PopWindow").show();
        });

        $("#Close").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#PopWindow").css({ "left": "0px", "top": "0px" });
            $("#PopWindow").hide();
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that tallcomponents does not work well with MVC. I would have wasted my day trying it

Answer (score 1):

A couple of years ago I had to do the same thing and solved everything with Aspose PDF for .Net. By that time it was nothing compared to what it is now and I was able to do exactly what you want, so my guessing is that by now it is even more powerful. The only problem is that it's not free, but it is not so expensive either. [Check it out](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx), or [Download](http://www.aspose.com/community/files/51/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/category1184.aspx) their trial version.

Good luck!
Hanlet

Comment: I am looking for free services , is there any one ?

Comment: what I want to do is not re-invent the wheel , I want just add another feature to my app , Creating Thumbnails for PDF files uploaded to galleries.